# Is it possible to make a string of JTextField variable

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I make some variable by

```
        String[] StoreValueFromTable = new String[5];
        String[] ColumName = new String[5];
        for(int Count=0;Count<5;Count++){
            StoreValueFromTable[Count] = "QueryTechnica"+Count;
            ColumName[Count] = "QT"+Count;
            System.out.println(StoreValueFromTable[Count]+", "+ColumName[Count]);
        }
```

I am trying to make `JTextField[] Fiels[Count] = new JTextField();` it's giving me error. I am not sure, is there a way to make it dynamically..

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear? Are you trying to make an array of `JTextField`s?

Comment: please post your error

Comment: Yes array of JTextField s.

Comment: ']' expected '}' expected @Clayton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
final int TEXTFIELDS_COUNT = 5; 
// Create an array of 5 JTextFields
JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[TEXTFIELDS_COUNT];

for(int count = 0; count< TEXTFIELDS_COUNT; count++){
    // fields[count] represents a single JTextField
    fields[count] = new JTextField();

    // Do something with fields[count], like setting its text 
    // fields[count].setText("some text");

    StoreValueFromTable[count] = "QueryTechnica"+count;
    ColumName[count] = "QT"+count;
    System.out.println(StoreValueFromTable[count]+", "+ColumName[count]);
}
```

Comment: instead of 5 you can mentioned count variable there

Comment: `count` is used as the iterator index. But he can define a constant for that.

Comment: But it will iterate only 5 times if we want that also dynamic then?

Comment: If you want to go dynamic, you'd better user a `List` instead.